# Android with Kotlin recyclerView with checkboxes randomly checked after delete list item

Tags: android, kotlin

apologies for my limited knowledge of programming and any sloppiness. I have a reyclerview with alarm objects that I can add and it creates them. When I add say 4 alarms, and delete three of them. The last alarms checkbox is checked by itself. I can not in anyway use the checkbox.setChecked() method for some reason. android studio is not recognizing it, if anyone could please let me know why that is. Also if you know of a solution to the auto check on the last alarm object please.

```
package com.example.alarmclock

import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Checkable
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.widget.doAfterTextChanged
import androidx.core.widget.doBeforeTextChanged
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.security.Key


 class AlarmAdapter (private val alarmList: MutableList<Alarm>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
//start viewholder
inner class ViewHolder(alarm: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(alarm) {
    val alarmLabel = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.alarmLabel)
    val editTextTime = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTime)
    val textView1 = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
    val deleteCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.deleteAlarmCheckBox)
    //val deleteButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.deleteAlarmButton)
    //val addButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.addAlarmButton)
    val mondayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.mondayCheckBox)
    val tuesdayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tuesdayCheckBox)
    val wednesdayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.wednesdayCheckBox)
    val thursdayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.thursdayCheckBox)
    val fridayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.fridayCheckBox)
    val saturdayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.saturdayCheckBox)
    val sundayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.sundayCheckBox)
    val amCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.amCheckBox)
    val pmCheckBox = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.pmCheckBox)
}//end viewholder




    fun addAlarm (alarm: Alarm) {
        alarmList.add(alarm)
        notifyItemInserted(alarmList.size - 1)
    }

    fun returnAlarmList (): MutableList<Alarm> {

        return alarmList
    }


    fun removeAlarms() {


       alarmList.removeAll {
            alarm -> alarm.deleteCheck == true
        }

        //notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun deleteAlarm (deletedAlarmList: List<Int> ) {

        val deletedListIterator = deletedAlarmList.iterator()
        val alarmListIterator = alarmList.iterator()
        while (deletedListIterator.hasNext()){
                while (alarmListIterator.hasNext()){
                    if (deletedListIterator.next() == alarmListIterator.next().alarmId){
                        alarmList.remove(alarmListIterator.next())
                    }
                }
        }

    }





override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {


    val context = parent.context
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val alarmView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarms, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(alarmView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return alarmList.size
}



override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AlarmAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val alarm: Alarm = alarmList[position]
    val alarmLabel = holder.alarmLabel
    var textView1 = holder.textView1
    var editTextTime = holder.editTextTime
    var mondayCheckBox = holder.mondayCheckBox
    var tuesdayCheckBox = holder.tuesdayCheckBox
    var wednesdayCheckBox = holder.wednesdayCheckBox
    var thursdayCheckBox = holder.thursdayCheckBox
    var fridayCheckBox = holder.fridayCheckBox
    var saturdayCheckBox = holder.saturdayCheckBox
    var sundayCheckBox = holder.sundayCheckBox
    var amCheckBox = holder.amCheckBox
    var pmCheckBox = holder.pmCheckBox
    var deleteAlarmCheckBox = holder.deleteCheckBox
    var lastCharacter = ""
    var secondLastCharacter = ""




    deleteAlarmCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.deleteCheck = !alarm.deleteCheck



    }

    alarmLabel.doAfterTextChanged {

        alarm.alarmLabel = alarmLabel.text.toString()
        textView1.text = alarm.alarmLabel
    }



   editTextTime.doAfterTextChanged {

       //lastCharacter = editTextTime.text.get(editTextTime.text.length-1).toString()
       textView1.text = lastCharacter
       if (editTextTime.text.length == 2 && secondLastCharacter != ":"){

           //if (lastCharacter != ":") {
               editTextTime.setText(editTextTime.text.toString().plus(":"))
               editTextTime.setSelection(editTextTime.text.length)
           //}

       }
       
       editTextTime.doBeforeTextChanged { _, _, _, _ ->
            if (editTextTime.length() != 0) {
                secondLastCharacter = editTextTime.text.get(editTextTime.text.length - 1).toString()
            }
       }

       


       if (editTextTime.text.length == 5 ){
           alarm.hour = editTextTime.text.get(0).toString().plus(editTextTime.text.get(1).toString())
           if (alarm.hour.toInt() < 10) alarm.hour = "0".plus(alarm.hour)



           ///////
           var inputedTimeList = editTextTime.text.toList()
           val timeIterator = inputedTimeList.iterator()
    

       }
   }

    mondayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.monday = !alarm.monday
        textView1.text = alarm.monday.toString()
    }
    tuesdayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.tuesday = !alarm.tuesday
    }
    wednesdayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {     
        alarm.wednesday = !alarm.wednesday
    }
    thursdayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.thursday = !alarm.thursday
    }
    fridayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.friday = !alarm.friday
    }
    saturdayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.saturday = !alarm.saturday
    }
    sundayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.sunday = !alarm.sunday
    }
    amCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
        alarm.amPm = !alarm.amPm
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, RecyclerView items are reused, so be sure that you set the all the values onBindViewHolder, because after your item is deleted, the actual view is not, so previously set values might be preset although they are not correct according to your data.

The easiest way would be to have **isChecked** Boolean value store in the **Alarm** object, **onBindViewHolder** always set the **isChecked** param on the Checkbox according to the value returned from the **Alarm** and when you change the **isChecked** inside the Checkbox listener - make sure you also update the value inside the **Alarm** object.

Another solution would be calling notifyDatasetChanged() on the RecyclerView, but it's definitely not the best solution especially if you have dynamic row deletion (and possibly a neat animation).

P.S. consider using viewBinding in your project, it will save you time writing all that ugly **findViewById** code :)))

Comment: Thanks much for the response.